# How to get collaboration ID using box api

Tags: box-api

I am trying to get the collaboration for a given folder. In the Box sdk given on github the function is public Collaboration GetCollaboration(string collaborationId, IEnumerable fields = null). My question is how do i get the collaboration ID??? After reading the  comments in [link] [Is there any way to get all files and folder in box without knowing their id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557657/is-there-any-way-to-get-all-files-and-folder-in-box-without-knowing-their-id/16579492#16579492) I thought the ID of a given folder is to be given but when i provide that I get an exception "404 not found". Although my folder id "867049500" does have a collaboration enabled. Please see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The official [Windows SDK](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2) provides [a method](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2/Managers/BoxFoldersManager.cs#L187-L202) that will fetch  the collaborations for a known folder:

```
var client = new BoxClient(...);
var collabs = await client.FoldersManager.GetCollaborationsAsync(folderId);
```

(Edited 8/29/14 to point to official SDK)

Comment: This answer is for the SDK that is no longer supported.  Is there a way using the Box API?

Comment: Updated answer to point to the official, supported Windows SDK

Answer (score 0):

- Rather than this i have been able to explore an alternative for this:

  `var boxManager = new BoxApi.V2.BoxManager(userToken);`
- From the above code you get the boxManager, and further:

  `var testFolder = boxManager.GetFolder(FolderID);`
- From the above code you get the Folder, and further pass it as shown below:

  `CollaborationCollection sampleCollabs = boxManager.GetCollaborations(testFolder, false, null);`

It has worked out for me, so i am sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, the following can get the collaboration attributes.

Step 1 : Use get_collaborations() method which returns a collaborations collection

```
collaborations = client.folder(folder_id='Your_target_folder_id').get_collaborations()
```

Step 2 : Then iterate over collaborations to get the specific collaboration ID

```
for collab in collaborations:
    collaboration_id = collab.id
```